# How to add 1 day to current date and have result in format yyyymmdd in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to add 1 day to the current date and have the output in the format yyyymmdd.
The code needs to be written on a stored procedure on the sql server.

currently my code is as follows:

```
 DECLARE @dat DATE

    select @dat = dateadd(DD, 1, getdate())
    SELECT @dat =LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @dat, 112),10)
```

However, it seems like im doing something wrong as my output on the sql table is in the format yyyy-mm-dd. I need to get rid of the hyphens.

any suggestions guys? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care about the dashes? You're returning a *date*, not a *string*. Worry about formatting on the client. Right now you're getting upset about how Management Studio is rendering the date to you. Also, please stop using lazy shorthand. Why is `DD` better than `DAY`?

Comment: Do you want a string or a date as the output of the Proc? If you need a date, then the format is irrelevant, if you need a string then change the declaration of @dat to a string.

Comment: thanks for the sugestions. wanted a string as the output.

Comment: `wanted a string as the output` for what possible purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @dat = dateadd(DD, 1, getdate())
DECLARE @datCus varchar(8)
select @datCus=LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @dat, 112),10)
```

The problem was that i assigned @dat to the insert statements values. However having a varchar variable to handle the converting part solved the problem (in this case @datCus).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are assigning it back to a date object.  You need to assign it to a varchar.

I did the following in SQL Server 2005:

```
DECLARE @dat DATETIME
DECLARE @string varchar(8)
SET @dat = GetUtcDate()

    select @dat = dateadd(DD, 1, getdate())

    SELECT @string =CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @dat, 112) 
PRINT @string
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration of @dat to a STRING

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(8)
SELECT @date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 112) 

SELECT @date
```